# "How to fix 'Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script"

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, https, github-pages

Trying to load my portfolio on Github pages but the carousel arrows do not move and in the inspection mode I see that there is an error on the line
 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js

Tried different using different links and scripts of jquery and Bootstrap

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.10/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<section class="success" id="projects">
    <center><h2>Projects</h2></center>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
 <!-- Carousel -->
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
   </ol>

   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
     <div class="item active">
       <center>    <p> <b>E-commerce Website:</b> <ol><br>
     <li >Constructed an E-commerce website for stationary equipment by implementing the MVC framework.</li><br>
     <li>Utilized Ruby on Rails technology to build a web application.</li></ol></P>  </center>
       </div>
     <div class="item">
       <center> <p> <b>Medassist Expert Medical Diagnosis System</b> <ol><br>
    <li> Designed the functional requirements and executed the test plan for the medical diagnosis system as a Quality Analyst. </li><br>
</ol></p> </center>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Enabled users to make online donations to Beta University and administrators to track donations.</li><br>
    <li>Created database with MySQL and utilized MS Visio to design the E-R and UML diagrams.</li><br>
     </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Left and right controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
 </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 Carousel must function properly as it does on local system.
```

Comment: Where did you include your CDN link in your document?

Comment: @Chizzele Added the scripts

Comment: Putting jQuery as the first script below the section tag should fix this

Comment: @Chizzele Used jQuery after section tag  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 no change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Preventing Mixed Content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content) go through the content and used appropriate Bootstrap and jquery version links.